# Как контролировать скрость прорисовки линий?

Tags: canvas, html, javascript

Всем доброго времени.

Необходимо со стороны клиента (в браузере) прорисовать эскиз, допустим, куба.
Под эскизом подразумевается простой рисунок линиями.
Сложность заключается в том, что линия должна появляться не сразу, а именно прорисовывается, т.е. рисоваться слева направо в течении 2 секунд.

На **canvas**е  через **canvas.getContext('2d')** прорисовать линии не тяжело, а вот как контролировать скрость прорисовки - не знаю.

Никто не знает как решить проблему?

P.S. не обязательно использовать canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это просто - нужно использовать функцию setTimeout(), которая будет запускать рисование примитивов отрезками нужного размера в нужный временной интервал.
Для простых случаев можно использовать [библиотеку](http://www.createjs.com/#!/TweenJS).